# how to display linked table value in list.gsp instead of id? Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

So I have two tables linked to each other, 
in `Create.gsp` I have a dropdown showing values from the other table, and when the user clicks on `save` it will store the `Id` of this value in the database,
However I want to show the value itself not the `id` on the list gsp 
is it possible?

I have two tables:

```
[Authors] - id - name

[Books] - id - title - author
```

In the Books form (create/edit) I can get the "author" field to display an author's name (from Author's table instead of `id`) without an issue, however when I view the /list/ view, it displays the author's `id` instead of the name (correctly, since this is what's stored in the `DB`).

Answer (score 2):

Override `toString` method in Author domain. Like this:

```
String toString(){
    name
}
```

Comment: what does it do exactly? I am still beginner in grails

Comment: Every time you display an instance in a view or use `println` to it, Grails creates a readable string. Its default `toString` method results in `Domain:id`. If you want to display something else, you can override that method and put your own implementation. If you use my example, both `println authorInstance` and `println authorInstance.name` will display author's name.

Comment: Another example of `toString` with Book domain is `String toString{ "$title by $author" }`; so each time you display a book it will show you something like "It by stephen King".

Answer (score 0):

Now you have list ID, so you can show the Value in you GSP Page by using OptionKey="id".

```
 // I guess your Value should be id here     
   <g:select name="author" from="${authors.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="author"
              value="${author?.id}"
              noSelection="['':'-- Select Author --']" />
```

If you store the value In your Database you can try the below code.

```
       <g:select name="author" from="${recommendation.list()}" 
          value="${author}"
          noSelection="['':'-- Select Author --']" />
```

Comment: actually this way didnt work, but I got it working eventually by adding the variable  to the value 
so this what I got on the List.gsp 
<td><g:link action="edit" id="${booksInstance.id}">${booksInstance?.author?.name}</g:link></td>

Thanks for your help Kamal!